# How to adjust existing code to do out of sample prediction in R

Tags: r, loops, rstudio, regression, prediction

I have a df as per below:

```
 Key  Date                     y   x1   x2   x3
   1    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   3    2    5
   1    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   5    7    2
   1    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    5   7    4    7 
   1    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   2    7    6
   2    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   6    3    8
   2    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   7    7    3
   2    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   2    3    4
   2    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   6    2    7
```

The following code enables me to run a regression against the "keys" and produce a prediction column within the data set I used to make the regression see code and example below:

```
test = df[(df$key==1 | df$key==2),]

df_list=split(test, test$key)
reg_results = lapply(df_list,function(temp) {

  good_cols=sapply(temp,function(x){
    is.numeric(x) && ((max(x)-min(x))!=0)
  })

  temp=temp[,good_cols]
  fit=lm(y~.,data=temp)
  return(fit)
})


#Credit to MrFlick for reg_predict code below

    reg_predict = dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
           data.frame(data, pred=predict(model))    }, df_list, reg_results))


df_list_summary = lapply(reg_results, function(model_output){
  broom::tidy(model_output)
})
final_step2 = dplyr::bind_rows(df_list_summary, .id="Key's")
readr::write_csv(final_step2,"test2.csv")
```

Example of what code produces:

```
 Key  Date                     y   x1   x2   x3  predicted values for each date
       1    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   3    2    5   ...
       1    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   5    7    2   ...
       1    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    5   7    4    7   ...
       1    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   2    7    6   ...
       2    1/10/2018 12:00:00 AM    2   6    3    8   ...
       2    1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   7    7    3   ...
       2    1/12/2018 12:00:00 AM    3   2    3    4   ...
       2    1/13/2018 12:00:00 AM    7   6    2    7   ...
```

Is there any way to adjust the line of code below, to enable the flexibility to predict out of sample using the regression built into the code before that? I have been trying and am not successful.

I have been playing with this line of code to solve my issue:

```
 reg_predict = dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
           data.frame(data, pred=predict(model))    }, df_list, reg_results))
```

Thank you kindly,

Comment: the exemplary data you gave does not contain a column with ((max(x)-min(x))>10000), can you edit so that the code you provided works as intended?

Comment: Use the `newdata` argument to predict: e.g. `predict(model,newdata=data)`

Comment: @tyumru edited as per request

Comment: @James I understand the predict function, but was unable to implement it to obtain desired result

Comment: @g3lo still not reproducible. Gives -Inf error for AIC

Comment: @tyumru I removed the step function and kept it simple lm, could you try again?

Comment: @tyumru did that work?

Comment: @g3lo Then I'm not clear what it is you are trying to do. Your example indicates you are only predicting from the model data.

Comment: @James thats correct. I am trying to adjust my code to enable it to predict for a sample outside the model. Im not sure how to adjust the code to enable it so that it can run a model as initial code, and than predict outside sample set.

Comment: @g3lo That's exactly what `newdata` is for.

Comment: @James if I try to simply put newdata = newdf in my existing code, it wont run. If anyone has advise on how I can implement this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @James here is the line of code I am tinkering with, where would 'newdata' go?

`reg_predict = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
  data.frame(data, pred=predict(model))
}, df_list, reg_results)),c(contains("scenario"), contains("date"), "sVAR", contains("pred")))`

Comment: @James if I put `pred = predict(model, newdata=newdf)` I get an error saying ` `Error in data.frame(data, pred = predict(model, newdata = test2)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 609, 1186`

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to put together the data from `data` and the predictions from `test2` which evidently have a different number of rows. If they had the same number of rows it would work, but likely be misleading as the predictions wouldn't necessarily relate to the data.

Comment: How would I fix this with my existing code? I would like the model to be made from one set of data, but adjust the code to predict from another?

Comment: Appreciate if anyone can assist still can't figure it out.

Comment: So when i try newdata in the following code:


`reg_predict = dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
           data.frame(data, pred=predict(model))    }, df_list, reg_results))`



I can't seem to point this code to work with a different data set to do out of sample prediction. I get the following error:



`Error in data.frame(data, pred = predict(model)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 593, 592 `

Can someone assist?

Comment: @James - All it is is a list of regressions that I am trying to point to a different set of data irrelevant of the number of rows, since all I want it to do is utilize the list of regressions and apply them to the various x variables contained in each list.

Comment: `data` and `predict(model)` clearly have a different number of rows. If you want to bind them together you should have the same number of rows. To ensure this, and for the binding to make sense, pass `data` in as the `newdata` parameter to `predict`.

Comment: I tried newdata as mentioned above, and it still provides error different number of rows.

Comment: @James when I put the following code:

`reg_predict = dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) { data.frame(data, pred=predict(model)) }, newdata=df_list, reg_results))`

I get this error:

`Error in (function (data, model)  : 
  unused argument (newdata = dots[[1]][[1]])`

Comment: @James so I figured it out, I had to put newdata 3 times throughout the code. 2 replacing "data" for "newdata" and once for predict(model,newdata).

The issue I am having now is, once I do out of sample prediction, sometimes the key's are not all there. And when I use the newdata to predict, what it does it uses the list of all regressions and applies each model in the order the list is stored. However, I just need it to predict per the key that matches the new data. For instance, if new data has key's 1,2, and 3. I want it to predict utilize only those regression models that match such keys

Comment: @James is there any way to do that?

Comment: @James here is what I have thus far, but can't get it to work:

`for (i in names(df_list)){
reg_predict = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(newdata, model) {
  data.frame(newdata, pred=predict(model,newdata))
}, df_list$i, reg_results$i)))
}`

When I run it, I get 0 in reg_predict. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oof_predictions_df = data.frame() 

for(i in seq(df_list)){ 
    g <- predict(reg_results2[[i]], df_list[[i]]) 
    f = data.frame(Key = df_list[[i]][,'Key'], Date = df_list[[i]][,'Dates'], NY = df_list[[i]][,'NY'], pred = g) 
    oof_predictions_df <- rbind(oof_predictions_df, f) 

}
```